# AutoNumeric - set a value after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this plugin : https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric

And I use this initialization :

```
AutoNumeric.multiple('.autonumeric-number', AutoNumericConfigDecimal);
AutoNumeric.multiple('.autonumeric-integer', AutoNumeric.getPredefinedOptions().integerPos);
```

And then, I have an Ajax call and I need to set the new value of my input. The problem is : I can't use `.set()` method of the plugin because it requires to have a variable you got after initialisation.

Since I use multiple selectors, I can't have this variable.

For now, I tried to initialize again :

```
// element already has mask
<input id="element" class="autonumeric-integer" />

// after ajax call
var element = new AutoNumeric('#element', AutoNumericConfig);
element.set(value);
```

But it doubles what I write in the input, "2" becomes "22".

Is it possible to use AutoNumeric functions using only the DOM element ? and not the variable you get after *initialization* ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the docs i see that there is a static method for finding the `AutoNumeric` instance that handles an element, named [`getAutoNumericElement`](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric#static-methods)

So if you have the `id` or a reference to the node you want you can pass it to this method and then you can call the `set()` on it.

```js
AutoNumeric.multiple('.autonumeric-integer', AutoNumeric.getPredefinedOptions().integerPos);


document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
// assuming you can target the elements based on id
  const element = AutoNumeric.getAutoNumericElement('#element3')
  element.set(13);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/autonumeric/4.1.0/autoNumeric.min.js"></script>

#element1: <input id="element1" class="autonumeric-integer" /><br/>
#element2: <input id="element2" class="autonumeric-integer" /><br/>
#element3: <input id="element3" class="autonumeric-integer" /><br/>
#element4: <input id="element4" class="autonumeric-integer" />

<button> update #element3 </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

This one-liner should work for you as well.

```
AutoNumeric.set('#element','2');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```js
new AutoNumeric('#revenue', {
    decimalPlaces: 0,
    unformatOnSubmit: true
}); //  add option `unformatOnSubmit:true`
```

or using:

```js
var revenue = AutoNumeric.getAutoNumericElement('.revenue');
var intRevenue = revenue.get();
```